# Private Ethereum Blockchain with 2 nodes sendTransaction() returns "invalid sender"

Tags: transactions, blockchain, ethereum

I have set up a private ethereum blockchain on a ubuntu VM. I have created 2 nodes and created an account on each of the nodes. I have mined some wei on both nodes/accounts and now was trying to send from one account to the other, with the following command:

`eth.sendTransaction({from: "0xd4b49495ea94285b0a8af7d813e089fc6c87311c", to: "0x45f42febec0ba6127ec1c7ce33d6f2afd0b9b24e", value: "800000000000000000"})`

However, I get the following error:

```
WARN [04-26|16:25:02.120] Served eth_sendTransaction               reqid=13 t=1.403564ms  err="invalid sender"
Error: invalid sender
    at web3.js:6347:37(47)
    at web3.js:5081:62(37)
    at <eval>:1:20(10)
```

*Edit:
This is how I go about trying to send:

I start node 1

```
docker run -it -p 8545:8545 -p 30303:30303 -v /Users/benjamin/myether/datadir1:/root/datadir mynode /bin/bash

geth --datadir=/root/datadir/ init /root/mygenesis.json

geth --datadir /root/datadir/ --networkid 1234 --port 30303 --rpcport 8545 --rpc --rpcapi eth,web3,personal,net --rpcaddr 0.0.0.0 console --allow-insecure-unlock
```

I start node 2:

```
docker run -it -p 8546:8545 -p 30304:30303 -v /Users/benjamin/myether/datadir2:/root/datadir mynode /bin/bash

geth --datadir=/root/datadir/ init /root/mygenesis.json

geth --datadir /root/datadir/ --networkid 1234 --port 30303 --rpcport 8545 -rpc --rpcapi eth,web3,personal,net --rpcaddr 0.0.0.0 console --allow-insecure-unlock
```

Then I unlock account on node 1:

```
personal.unlockAccount("0xd4b49495ea94285b0a8af7d813e089fc6c87311c", pass phrase)
```

Then I use the sendTransaction() as specified above on node 1.

My Dockerfile:

```
FROM ubuntu:20.04
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y software-properties-common net-tools
RUN add-apt-repository -y ppa:ethereum/ethereum && apt-get update
RUN apt-get -y install ethereum
ADD ./genesis.json /root/mygenesis.json
EXPOSE 8545 8546 30303 30303/udp
RUN mkdir -p /root/datadir
ENTRYPOINT "bash"
```

My genesis.json:

```
  "alloc": {},
  "coinbase"   : "0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000",
  "difficulty" : "0x20000",
  "extraData"  : "",
  "gasLimit"   : "0x2fefd8",
  "nonce"      : "0x0000000000000042",
  "mixhash"    : "0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000",
  "parentHash" : "0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000",
  "timestamp"  : "0x00",
  "config":{
    "chainId": 813
  }
}
```

### For the most part I followed this tutorial: https://pragmaticintegrator.wordpress.com/2017/11/05/set-up-private-blockchain-with-ethereum-part-2/

I am just starting out on the topic and don't really understand most of what is happening. Is it possible that I somehow have to sign the transaction? How would I do this?

Thank you for any help, I appreciate it.

Comment: Please edit your question and show how you use the `eth.sendTransaction`. Do you input it in the node console (which node? geth? openethereum? other?) or use it in a JavaScript snippet with `web3js`? ... Most likely your transaction is not signed. But how to sign it - it depends on how you create the transaction and send it to the node.

Comment: @PetrHejda, thank you for your quick response, I appreciate it. I tried to edit my question and make it as detailed as possible.